# Duplicate Output from the powershell script

Tags: powershell

The below script gives me duplicate results, could you please let me know where is the mistake in this script?
In output if you see myserver2 has duplicate entries.

```
Get-Content "C:\test\computers.txt" | ForEach-Object { $_.TrimEnd() } | ForEach-Object {
    $value += Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Param($computer)

        # Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter
        $SqlQuery = "xp_fixeddrives"
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$computer;Initial Catalog='Secaudit';Integrated Security = True";
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlQuery, $Sqlconnection)

        $mdtable = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
        $nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($mdtable)
        $nRecs | Out-Null
        $mdtable.Tables[0]

        for ($i=0; $i -lt $mdtable.tables.count; $i++) {
            $res = $mdtable.Tables[$i]
        }

        $res
    } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred
}

$value
```

Output (I have changed the server names):

```
PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : C
MB free            : 77659

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : E
MB free            : 143104

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : F
MB free            : 470680

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : G
MB free            : 34955

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : C
MB free            : 77659

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : E
MB free            : 143104

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : F
MB free            : 470680

PSComputerName     : myserver1
RunspaceId         : a1bd8b88-21b4-4b9c-ba1c-1e189b69fdfe
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : G
MB free            : 34955

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : C
MB free            : 11393

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : G
MB free            : 16456

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : H
MB free            : 397295

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : I
MB free            : 389523

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : J
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : K
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : L
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : M
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : N
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : O
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : P
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : Q
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : R
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : S
MB free            : 1225745

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : T
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : X
MB free            : 184221

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : C
MB free            : 11393

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : G
MB free            : 16456

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : H
MB free            : 397295

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : I
MB free            : 389523

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : J
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : K
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : L
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : M
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : N
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : O
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : P
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : Q
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : R
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : S
MB free            : 1225745

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : T
MB free            : 409494

PSComputerName     : myserver2
RunspaceId         : 0575a3e3-37f7-4db9-ac9e-70e7ef5501b7
PSShowComputerName : True
drive              : X
MB free            : 184221
```

Comment: Does it change anything if you initialize `$value` as an empty array, for example ? `$value = @()` (before `Get-Content`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mdtable.Tables[0]
```

is added to `$value`, then `$res`, which also is `$mdtable.Tables[0]` on the first cycle of the loop.

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you think is the issue, I'm not sure about this

Comment: The line should just be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ansgar.

Comment: @SaikiranParamkusham The answer was posted by Jaqueline Vanek.

Answer (score -2):

For ensuring that $value is filled with only this info:
change $value += 
in $value =
If you stil get doubles after that, check the sql-query on double values

Comment: Hi, welcome, your answer is incomplete, because you lack information from the original poster. To avoid being flamed (votes) you should remove  it. To request clarification, you are supposed to leave a comment on the question, but you only will be able to do it when you have acquired 50 reputation points on this site - those are the rules.